# IntelliJ Ultimate 2019.3 find usages not working

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

if i use maven propertie dynamic generation version in multi-module, find usages not working.

projecdt structure:
-parent-project
--api
--service

parent:

```xml
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>develop</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <profile-version>dev</profile-version>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>qas</id>
            <properties>
                <profile-version>qas</profile-version>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>master</id>
            <properties>
                <profile-version>prd</profile-version>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

api:

```xml
<properties>
   <profile-version>dev</profile-version>
</properties>

<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>artifactId/artifactId>
<version>1.0-${profile-version}-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

```java
public interface TestService {
  public void test();
}
```

servcie: find TestService usages not working.

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>groupId</groupId>
   <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-${profile-version}-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

```java
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {
  public void test(){}
}
```

Comment: The 2019.3 is quite an old build. Please check if the problem reproduces in the 2022.2 build from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download .

Comment: That is also not supported by Maven `1.0-${profile-version}-SNAPSHOT`... if you like to use versions more flexible use this: https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html but it looks like you should versions different than a profile..

Comment: Check the usage of this profile...because that looks wrong and I would like to know why do you need to do that?

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks in advance. Because i have three environments, each of which maintains its own version. I am sure `1.0-${profile-version}-SNAPSHOT`  is work, but IntelliJ is not well analyze.  It's ok, it's just a small problem.

Comment: Three different environment means having different sets of configuration files but not different jar files..furthermore the given usage of the `1.0-${profile-version}-SNAPSHOT` will not work correctly as I already mentioned. Using profiles for such things is the wrong way...

Comment: @khmarbaise You're right, I'll try other ways, such as [maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html](https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html).  Thanks again.